# Создать функцию, сортирующую данную структуру (например, по частоте посещений в неделю), и функцию для изменения информ

Tags: c, алгоритм

Пожалуйста, помогите написать функцию, которая отсортирует структуру по частоте посещений ПУЗЫРЬКОМ. Основной Код есть, нужен только фрагмент кода сортировки. Заранее спасибо.
Полное задание: Создать массив, элементами которого являются структуры – список клиентов фитнесс-клуба (фамилия, частота
посещений в неделю, личный тренер). Создать функцию, сортирующую данную структуру (например, по частоте
посещений в неделю), и функцию для изменения информации клиента. Использовать эти функции по назначению в
программе (для вывода отсортированной информации и изменения нужной информации)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define LEN 4

struct clients {
    char fam[15];
    int chastota;
    char trener[15];
};

int main() {
    system("chcp 1251 > nul");

    struct clients mas_struct[LEN] =
    { {"Иванов",2,"Омаров"},
    {"Петров",3,"Снегов"},
    {"Сидоров",1,"Онегин"},
    {"Курочкин",4,"Панин"} };



    int find(char* str) {
        int i;

        for (i = 0; i < LEN; i++) {
            if (strcmp(mas_struct[i].fam, str) == 0) return i;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    void update()
    {
        int i, chastota, q;
        char trener[15], surname[15];

        printf("Enter surname: ");
        gets(surname);
        i = find(surname);
        if (i >= 0) {
            printf("Enter new fam of trener: ");
            scanf("%s", &trener);
            strcpy(mas_struct[i].trener, trener);
            printf("Enter new chastota: ");
            scanf("%d", &q);
            mas_struct[i].chastota = q;
        }
        else
            printf("Part not found.\n");
    }

    printf("\nНаша таблица:");
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        printf("\n%15s %d %10s ", mas_struct[i].fam, mas_struct[i].chastota, mas_struct[i].trener);
    printf("\n");

    //ФУНКЦИЯ СОРТИРОВКИ

        printf("\nНаша таблица:");
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        printf("\n%15s %d %10s ", mas_struct[i].fam, mas_struct[i].chastota, mas_struct[i].trener);
    printf("\n");

    update();

    printf("\nНаша таблица:");
    for (int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        printf("\n%15s %d %10s ", mas_struct[i].fam, mas_struct[i].chastota, mas_struct[i].trener);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Нет ничего проще, чем нагуглить код сортировки пузырьком.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!